# ¿como usar la siguiente consulta en una función de mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Buen dia estoy realizando un ejercicio en MySQL workbench el cual es mostrar cuantos articulos se tienen por cada editorial.

este es el script de los datos:

```
CREATE TABLE Articulo(
idArticulo INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
titulo VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
autor VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
edicion VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
precio INT NOT NULL);
```

//insercion de datos

```
INSERT INTO Articulo(idArticulo, titulo, autor, edicion, precio)
VALUES (1, 'Redes cisco', 'Ernesto Arigasello', 'Alfaomega-Rama', 60000),
(2, 'Facebook y twitter para adultos', 'Veloso Claudio', 'Alfaomega', 52000),
(3, 'Creacion de un portal con php y mysql', 'Jacobo Pavon Puertas', 'Alfaomega-Rama', 40000),
(4, 'Administracion de sistemas operativos', 'Julio Gomez Lopez', 'Alfaomega-Rama', 55000);
```

// esta es la consulta que tengo que pasar a una funcion

```
/* Mostrar cuantos articulos se tienen de cada editorial */
SELECT edicion, COUNT(*) FROM articulo
GROUP BY edicion;
```

el resultado de la consulta es

```
alfaomega-rama 3
alfaomega      1
```

hasta aqui todo bien per cuando lo quiero hacer en una funcion

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE FUNCTION articulosPorEditorial() RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
BEGIN
DECLARE numero VARCHAR(30);
SELECT CONCAT(edicion,COUNT(*)) INTO numero FROM Articulo GROUP BY edicion;
RETURN numero;
END
$
```

//aparece el siguiente error

> 14:24:47  SELECT articulosPorEditorial()  LIMIT 0, 1000   Error Code:
>   1172. Result consisted of more than one row   0.000 sec

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para futuras preguntas, considera identar el código, seleccionado cada bloque de código y presionando  luego sobre el símbolo `{ }` del panel superior cuando la edición está activada. Gracias.

Comment: La funcion debe devolver un solo numero. Si vos agrupas por todas las ediciones, hay mas de un numero ;). Sera que te falta un where?

Comment: Lo cierto es que no tengo la respuesta de como seria, pero a golpe de vista, si una función retorna un Varchar(30) y tu consulta retorna mas de una linea, tira ese error, lo correcto seria, o bien tu funcion retorna una tabla (un set de registros y columnas) (Que no sé como se hace o si se puede) o bien retorna todas las lineas concatenadas gracias a un [Group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) ejecutado en base a tu consulta. PD: Puedes crear tu ejemplo en [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) y compartir el linck en la pregunta.

Comment: @gbianch te refieres a usar un limit 1 en la condicion where?     requiero hacer esta consulta                                                    SELECT edicion, COUNT(*) FROM articulo
GROUP BY edicion;                                                                                   /* pero en una funcion*/

Comment: el comentario de Ricardo es la respuesta que estas buscando